# How to store json elements from one json file into another json file?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

I have a json file. Here is a sample of what it looks like:

```html
*{
            "_id": "5f70aa5c04d7a034fc19e8969b000599",
            "contributors": null,
            "coordinates": null,
            "created_at": "Wed May 06 09:32:46 +0000 2020",
            "display_text_range": [
                13,
                35
            ],
            "entities": {
                "hashtags": [],
                "symbols": [],
                "urls": [],
                "user_mentions": [
                    {
                        "id": 1213834918263869400,
                        "id_str": "1213834918263869442",
                        "indices": [
                            0,
                            12
                        ],
                        "name": "D!@n@(ام علي)",
                        "screen_name": "Dianamh2312"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "favorite_count": 0,
            "favorited": false,
            "filter_level": "low",
            "geo": null,
            "id": 1257966527946473500,
            "id_str": "1257966527946473472",
            "in_reply_to_screen_name": "Dianamh2312",
            "in_reply_to_status_id": 1257909535752310800,
            "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "1257909535752310784",
            "in_reply_to_user_id": 1213834918263869400,
            "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "1213834918263869442",
            "is_quote_status": false,
            "lang": "ar",
            "place": {
                "attributes": {},
                "bounding_box": {
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                150.520929,
                                -34.118347
                            ],
                            [
                                150.520929,
                                -33.578141
                            ],
                            [
                                151.343021,
                                -33.578141
                            ],
                            [
                                151.343021,
                                -34.118347
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "type": "Polygon"
                },
                "country": "Australia",
                "country_code": "AU",
                "full_name": "Sydney, New South Wales",
                "id": "0073b76548e5984f",
                "name": "Sydney",
                "place_type": "city",
                "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/0073b76548e5984f.json"
            },
            "quote_count": 0,
            "reply_count": 0,
            "retweet_count": 0,
            "retweeted": false,
            "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>",
            "text": "@Dianamh2312 يسعد اوقاتك ام علي ",
            "timestamp_ms": "1588757566807",
            "truncated": false,
            "user": {
                "contributors_enabled": false,
                "created_at": "Mon Dec 11 11:29:28 +0000 2017",
                "default_profile": true,
                "default_profile_image": false,
                "description": "اَللّـهُمَّ اكْشِفْ هذِهِ الْغُمَّةَ عَنْ هذِهِ الاُْمَّةِ بِحُضُورِهِ ، وَ عَجِّلْ لَنا ظُهُورَهُ ، اِنَّهُمْ يَرَوْنَهُ بَعيداً وَ نَراهُ قَريباً.",
                "favourites_count": 8338,
                "follow_request_sent": null,
                "followers_count": 5208,
                "following": null,
                "friends_count": 5097,
                "geo_enabled": true,
                "id": 940181735601455100,
                "id_str": "940181735601455106",
                "is_translator": false,
                "lang": null,
                "listed_count": 0,
                "location": null,
                "name": "iman",
                "notifications": null,
                "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
                "profile_background_image_url": "",
                "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
                "profile_background_tile": false,
                "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/940181735601455106/1584734762",
                "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1246607950392840192/QmN6Qf50_normal.jpg",
                "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1246607950392840192/QmN6Qf50_normal.jpg",
                "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
                "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
                "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
                "profile_text_color": "333333",
                "profile_use_background_image": true,
                "protected": false,
                "screen_name": "Hageiman",
                "statuses_count": 4607,
                "time_zone": null,
                "translator_type": "none",
                "url": null,
                "utc_offset": null,
                "verified": false
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f70aa5c04d7a034fc19e8969b0007dd",
            "contributors": null,
            "coordinates": null,
            "created_at": "Wed May 06 09:33:34 +0000 2020",
            "display_text_range": [
                12,
                33
            ],
            "entities": {
                "hashtags": [],
                "symbols": [],
                "urls": [],
                "user_mentions": [
                    {
                        "id": 1099969756805906400,
                        "id_str": "1099969756805906434",
                        "indices": [
                            0,
                            11
                        ],
                        "name": "jamal199",
                        "screen_name": "jamal19918"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "favorite_count": 0,
            "favorited": false,
            "filter_level": "low",
            "geo": null,
            "id": 1257966726299316200,
            "id_str": "1257966726299316230",
            "in_reply_to_screen_name": "jamal19918",
            "in_reply_to_status_id": 1257937052097745000,
            "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "1257937052097744896",
            "in_reply_to_user_id": 1099969756805906400,
            "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "1099969756805906434",
            "is_quote_status": false,
            "lang": "ar",
            "place": {
                "attributes": {},
                "bounding_box": {
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                150.520929,
                                -34.118347
                            ],
                            [
                                150.520929,
                                -33.578141
                            ],
                            [
                                151.343021,
                                -33.578141
                            ],
                            [
                                151.343021,
                                -34.118347
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "type": "Polygon"
                },
                "country": "Australia",
                "country_code": "AU",
                "full_name": "Sydney, New South Wales",
                "id": "0073b76548e5984f",
                "name": "Sydney",
                "place_type": "city",
                "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/0073b76548e5984f.json"
            },
            "quote_count": 0,
            "reply_count": 0,
            "retweet_count": 0,
            "retweeted": false,
            "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>",
            "text": "@jamal19918 صباح النور jamal ",
            "timestamp_ms": "1588757614098",
            "truncated": false,
            "user": {
                "contributors_enabled": false,
                "created_at": "Mon Dec 11 11:29:28 +0000 2017",
                "default_profile": true,
                "default_profile_image": false,
                "description": "اَللّـهُمَّ اكْشِفْ هذِهِ الْغُمَّةَ عَنْ هذِهِ الاُْمَّةِ بِحُضُورِهِ ، وَ عَجِّلْ لَنا ظُهُورَهُ ، اِنَّهُمْ يَرَوْنَهُ بَعيداً وَ نَراهُ قَريباً.",
                "favourites_count": 8339,
                "follow_request_sent": null,
                "followers_count": 5208,
                "following": null,
                "friends_count": 5097,
                "geo_enabled": true,
                "id": 940181735601455100,
                "id_str": "940181735601455106",
                "is_translator": false,
                "lang": null,
                "listed_count": 0,
                "location": null,
                "name": "iman",
                "notifications": null,
                "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
                "profile_background_image_url": "",
                "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
                "profile_background_tile": false,
                "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/940181735601455106/1584734762",
                "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1246607950392840192/QmN6Qf50_normal.jpg",
                "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1246607950392840192/QmN6Qf50_normal.jpg",
                "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
                "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
                "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
                "profile_text_color": "333333",
                "profile_use_background_image": true,
                "protected": false,
                "screen_name": "Hageiman",
                "statuses_count": 4608,
                "time_zone": null,
                "translator_type": "none",
                "url": null,
                "utc_offset": null,
                "verified": false
            }
        },*
```

I am writing a basic json script to fetch the data from this file where **lang="ar"** 
The code is as follows:

```html
 var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./instance3_u.json', 'utf8', (err, jsonString) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error reading file from disk:", err)
        return
    }
    try {
        const db = JSON.parse(jsonString)
        var count = Object.keys(db.docs).length;

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (db.docs[i].lang === "ar") {
            console.log(db.docs[i]._id, '\n', db.docs[i].text, '\n', db.docs[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0], '\n', db.docs[i].lang, '\n')
                var data_ar = {
                    id: db.docs[i]._id,
                    text: db.docs[i].text,
                    coordinates: db.docs[i].place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0],
                    lang: db.docs[i].lang
                }
                var data = JSON.stringify(data_ar)
                fs.writeFileSync('data_ar.json', data);
            }
            
        }
       
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Error parsing JSON string:', err)
    }
})
```

The console prints the required output.
When I try to store this output into another json file called **data_ar** , it just gives me the last value of **i**.
I want to store the entire data that I am printing in ***console***

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.writeFileSync('data_ar.json', data);` This line creates that data_ar.json file everytime you call it. So that's why you only see the last one in the array. You should use `fs.appendFileSync` method instead.

Edit: As asked in the comments the JSON created in the first example wasn't valid. To make it valid it needs to be an array. The easier way of creating array is filtering and mapping the original array then you can use `writeFileSync` because you will do just 1 writing operation.

```
const data = db.docs.filter(d=> d.lang === "ar").map(d=>
                ({
                    id: d._id,
                    text: d.text,
                    coordinates: d.place.bounding_box.coordinates[0][0],
                    lang: d.lang
                  }));

    fs.writeFileSync('data_ar.json', data);
```

Comment: So, the output json file I get doesnt have commas in it. How do I modify the above code so that I have commas and the end of each json element?